# I'm unsure on how to save my float value on pause/destroy of the app

Tags: java, android, savestate

I have an app where clicking an image makes a value (goldCount) increase by 1. When run, the app runs a splash, before starting the app. However, should I minimize or close the game, the goldCount value reverts to 0.0, and tutorials on SharedPreferences are giving me no clues as to how I may go about saving the float value.

My Main Java code:

```
package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public float goldCount = 0.0f;
Button minionClick;
TextView textGoldCount;
String textTotal;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





    //Set fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);



    //Linking the variables
    minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
    textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

    //String which will display at the top of the app
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

    //Setting TextView to the String
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
    textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
    textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

    //Setting onClickListener
    minionClick.setClickable(true);

    minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.minioncentreid:
    goldCount += 1.0;
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    break;
    }


}
```

}

My Splash code, if it's relevant:

```
package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(splashBundle);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);



    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent("com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.CLICKER");
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
            finish();   
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: In your code i don't see where you use SharedPreferences

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how to use them.
Do you know anywhere that shows you how to save float variables in SharedPreferences, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question, but in your `Splash` code, instead of creating a new thread, do the following:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent("com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.CLICKER");
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}, 2000);
```

It is much cleaner and is the preferred in most cases when defining a delayed action.

To answer your question, it seems that you are not dealing with anything to actually save the value of `goldCount`.

At the top of the class do the following. "APP_NAME_HERE" should be replaced with your application name, or any sort of key for that matter.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("APP_NAME_HERE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In your onCreate method, do the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // other onCreateStuff

    goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

    // other onCreateStuff
}
```

And then in your `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.minioncentreid:
            goldCount += 1.0;
            prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
            textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
            textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
            textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This really helps a lot! The only problem is that I apparently need a "corresponding commit()" for the edit() to save the value :\

Comment: prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount); to prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit(); -- You should commit the changes to the file.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did whilst I was trying to figure it out - The error went away, but the app now won't run, and I'm getting [this list of errors in LogCat.](http://i.imgur.com/GzLqs0q.png) :|